# Ububtu, How to fix "Child Task Failure on Deployment"

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, checksum, shinyapps

I can run my Shiny app on the server but cannot deploy it. Here are the steps I take:

1) I start up Ubuntu as admin

2)

```
sudo R
library(rsconnect)
```

3) change directory to the folder containing the Shiny Web App

4)

```
deployApp()
```

5) Am met with this error message:

```
    error parsing manifest
    #############Begin Task Log##############
    #############End Task Log################
    Error unhandled exception: Child Task 631308703 failed: error parsing manifest: Maifest file app.R checksum mistmatch
```

The directory I am in contains only the Shiny Web App file, so I'm not sure what the error is referring to. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, you will have to provide a [mcve]. Also, don't link images from some external site, copy'n'paste the text instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt should be good now

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using my Windows RStudio to publish the code. A few packages needed to be installed as well, and everything after was smooth sailing.